# vslam, Running on Your Own Data

Tags: ros, visual-odometry, vslam-system, vslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I want to use the vslam package in diamondback for visual odometry. I made all the installation steps, downloaded the stereo tutorial data and tested. It works fine, but know i have some problems trying to use my own data instead of the tutorial bag.

In the section "1.4 Running on Your Own Data" you explain how to use your own data just changing some lines in the stereo_vslam.launch.

My bag had the stereo images unsynchronized, I play my bag and launch the sync_images node and had the stereo images synchronized. But still have some problems using the vslam node. I can run the sync images and the vslam_system without problems, but when i play the bag the vslam_system node says:

[wide_stereo/stereo_vslam_node-1] process has died [pid 20722, exit code -11].
log files: /home/joser/.ros/log/d398d566-cdd9-11e0-8873-f30ac7586bf8/wide_stereo-stereo_vslam_node-1*.log

The only difference that i can see between the playing the two bags (tutorial and my own) using the rxgraph is the subscription of "/tf" topic (with the tutorial bag the vslam_node achieved the subscription and with my bag it didn't)

In the log file it say : [roscpp_internal] [2011-08-24 00:47:55,900] [thread 0x7f53a928c860]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [searchParam] returned an error (-1): [Cannot find parameter [tf_prefix] in an upwards search]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-08-24 00:47:55,902] [thread 0x7f53a928c860]: [DEBUG] Publisher update for [/tf]:  already have these connections:
[roscpp_internal] [2011-08-24 00:47:55,902] [thread 0x7f53a928c860]: [DEBUG] Creating intraprocess link for topic [/tf]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-08-24 00:47:55,903] [thread 0x7f53a928c860]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [lookupService] returned an error (-1): [no provider] ...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10951/vslam,-running-on-your-own-data/) by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 370 on 2011-08-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on 2011-08-24**:
Thanks you very much!! with the sync_images node I have my stereo images synchronized! But still have some problems with the vslam node.. it says [wide_stereo/stereo_vslam_node-1] process has died [pid 20722, exit code -11]. log files: /home/joser/.ros/log/d398d566-cdd9-11e0-8873-f30ac7586bf8/wide_stereo-stereo_vslam_node-1*.log -

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-08-23**:
Please update your original question with new information instead of posting "answers" that don't answer the question. This will help keep ROS Answers easy to read in the future. Thanks for helping to keep ROS Answers well organized!

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-08-18**:
Do you have *exactly* synchronized images? The tutorial mentions in section 1.2 which messages are required. That was my biggest hurdle to getting started, solved using the ROS node [http://ibotics.ucsd.edu/stingray/browser/branches/rostingray/sync_images | sync_images]. Any error messages for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

vslam is experimental research code. It is not actively being supported, and should be used at your own risk, but patches are welcome.

If you would like a robust method of localization and mapping with a stereo camera or kinect, use the 2D slam_gmapping stack. See the pointcloud_to_laserscan package from the turtlebot stack and the SLAM Gmapping with Kinect Tutorial for the turtlebot.

---

Originally posted by [Helen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1033/helen/) with karma: 261 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0